# Raw Notification Handling in UI inside my App in Windows Phone 8

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-8, notifications

Can some one help me out in showing a TextBox in all screens after parsing a Raw Notification data. I'm successfully able to show this data on a MessageBox like the code below but unable to show in TextBox and I want this TextBox to be called from any screen in my app. How can I do this?

```
public void PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived(object sender, HttpNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        string message;

        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Notification.Body))
        {
            message = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("This is a "+message);

        var RawNotification = (RawData)serializer.ReadObject(e.Notification.Body);*/

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
              MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Received Notification {0}:\n{1}",
              DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), message))
        );



    }
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: Its crashing the App.

Comment: I can able to see MessageBox no matter where I'm in the App. Like even though I 'm using above code in MainPage.xaml but I'm still able to see it on Page2.xaml without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for one of my app. I Don't know if this is correct way of doing it or not but it solved my purpose.

1) First Create a UserControl in whatever look and feel you want to have. Make sure you create a Public Variable that will accept String ( In this case your Message )

2) Create a method in App.xaml.cs with String parameter ( To Pass your message string ). Withing the Method, Do a Dispatcher which will call a Messagebox with Content as the usercontrol. When invoking the UserControl, Pass your message as parameter.

Now whenerver or wherever you want to display a message, Use this method from App.xaml.cs and then you can create this textbox update.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your solution but when I'm trying to create a method in App.xaml.cs class, its not accepting the Dipatcher.

Comment: My problem remained that how do I listen in all screens if a notification is received or not. I'm able to that on MainPage.xaml but not any other page.